# Creating a pie highchart from Data in local (OBJECT) JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, highcharts

**This is my JSON data in my JSON file**

> {"diskspace":100,"diskspace.free":50,"time":8,"time.played":2,"controllers":25,"controllers.used":3,
>   "controllers.new":10, "controllers.broken":12}

What I am trying to do is to display the Json data above in several forms of a pie charts. For example one pie chart that will display diskspace/diskspace.free which will basically be a 50%50 chart.

The problem is that I couldn't get the data to be displayed from my Json file when its in the shown format. However if I change the json data in the file to a col and row format I managed to find a way to display it but that is inconvenient as I need to create a separate json file for every chart.

Right now all it returns is a blank page which I beleive it does contains an empty chart therefor its not visible.

**Here is my JS**

```
var app = angular.module('charts', []);

app.directive('highchart', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch(function () { return attrs.chart; }, function () {

            if (!attrs.chart) return;

            var charts = JSON.parse(attrs.chart);

            $(element[0]).highcharts(charts);

        });
    }
};
});


app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http.get('bla.json').success(function (key, data) {

    // var score = [];
    // for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //     score.push(data[i]);   
    // }

    // var name = [];
    // for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //     name.push(data[i].key);
    // }

    $scope.renderChart = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },

        series: [{
            data: data
        }],
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        }
    };
}).error("error message");
$timeout($scope.fetch, 1000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Dashboard Application</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>
  <section ng-app="charts">
   <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <highchart chart='{{renderChart}}'></highchart>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="record in overSpeedWorstRecords">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

I also created a [plunker LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/MXpyp1e8c6pI9gFHljDx?p=preview) so feel free to adjust it and your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format isn't really.. easy to parse. I mean, in **keys** you have distinct names, which is hard to define rules for parsing. Why not using something like this:

```
{
  "diskspace": [
    ["total", 100],
    ["free",50]
  ],
  "time": [
    ["total", 8],
    ["played", 2]
  ],
  "controllers": [
    ["total", 25], 
    ["used", 3], 
    ["new", 10], 
    ["broken",12]
  ]
}
```

Now you can create multiple pie charts: http://plnkr.co/edit/AqVbfE3mxCf7ahAfKtRG?p=preview

Simple improvement for your controller:

```
var series = [],
    iterator = 1;

for (var key in keys) {
  series.push({
    data: keys[key], // add data from the new format
    center: [(25 * iterator) + '%', '50%'] // calculate where center of the pie should be
  });
  iterator++;
};

$scope.renderChart = {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        size: '25%' // change size of the pies
      }
    },
    series: series,
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    }
};
```

Note: I am not sure how exactly those charts should be rendered (time vs time.played? Or time+time.played vs time.played?) as the pie chart. In my opinion, may be a better choice for your use case: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bydq5NG6BkG2LOqhQwzF?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your help Pawel, the problem is that I don't have the luxury of re-formatting my JSON data because I am going to be using a JSON file that is produced by a server which contains data with the format I showed at the beginning. So I have to use that (all data in 1 object) format with no arrays. Is it not possible doing it with the same JSON format I posted initially?

Comment: I see. It may be hard, but here is a general idea, how I would parse such data: http://plnkr.co/edit/HgBt03nwcf0jbHtuJyoD?p=preview

Comment: Again thank you that was very helpful. If you don't mind me asking about one more thing, if you look at the my initial plunker (after adding your updated parsing method) I changed the json data slightly and added extra data that I don't want to appear in a chart(any data that wasn't in the previous json on you plunker version). To make it more clear, is it possible to fetch only specific data from json file to the chart while passing over the unnecesary data we dont want in a chart?
Your time is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Just don't push to series array objects you don't want to. For example, you can create an array with allowed / disallowed keys from your JSON and search if should be added. That's the reason why in the first place I suggested to change your JSON format. You need a lot of extra logic just to change JSON. Here is simple example for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/DWomt4VWXA2uvJ2jSZcM?p=preview

Comment: You've been of GREAT help! Thank you very much for the guidance I highly appreciate it. I marked your answer as the correct one.